# Python Selenium .click() Not Working but Server Response is 200

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution. I'm writing code in Python using the Selenium library to pull reports from a site we utilize. In order to access the reports, it has to click on a link to expand so the code can find the report names. The issue I'm running into is the code is running fine and clicking on the link, but the link isn't expanding to reveal the reports. Debugging is saying that the link is found and clicked with a post response of 200, but nothing is happening. Due to the nature of the response code saying everything is fine, I'm at a loss of why the folder isn't expanding. Due to the nature of the site, I cannot share too much but have attached my code that I can share along with screenshots.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver_chrom, 30)

def Try_Wait(args, thing_string):
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(args))
        logger_write.debug("found element "+thing_string)
        #print("found args for ", thing_string)
        return
    except:
        Exit_LogOut()
        driver_chrom.quit()
        sys.exit()

def Button_Click(args, thing_string):
    try:
        driver_chrom.find_element(*args).click()
        logger_write.debug("Found button click"+thing_string)
        #print('clicking button for ', thing_string)
        return
    except:
        #print('did not click button ', thing_string)
        logger_write.error("Did not find button "+thing_string)
        return

thing_string = 'Opening folder for reports'
Try_Wait((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="folder1"]/table/tbody/tr//td[a[starts-with(@href, "javascript:clickOnNode(") and contains(@href, "1") and contains(text(),"Standard")]]'), thing_string)
Button_Click((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="folder1"]/table/tbody/tr//td[a[starts-with(@href, "javascript:clickOnNode(") and contains(@href, "1") and contains(text(),"Standard")]]'), thing_string)
```

This is what it looks like after code above runs
[image]

This is what it should look like so that reports are loaded into the html
[image]

Here is the inspect screenshot:
[image]

Comment: try to screenshot what's seeing the driver with `driver_chrom.save_screenshot(‘ss.png’)` to have a better understanding of the issue. Maybe the driver is seeing something else

Comment: the screenshot is matching my first image

edit: as an fyi I had added the following after the button_click:  
short_wait = WebDriverWait(driver_chrom, 5)
short_wait
screen_shot_loc = download_loc+"\\ss.png"
driver_chrom.save_screenshot(screen_shot_loc)

Comment: @Ryan_The_Noob, Your `xpath` seems invalid. Please post the relevant html.

Comment: @Kunduk, I've added a screenshot of the inspect. Both the functions Try_Wait and Button_Click are returning 200 post, so I'm assuming the XPath was valid. Am I incorrect in that assumption?

Comment: @Ryan_The_Noob : I have added the `xpath` please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following `xpath` should work for you.

```
//a[text()="Standard"]
```

Instead this

```
//div[@id="folder1"]/table/tbody/tr//td[a[starts-with(@href, "javascript:clickOnNode(") and contains(@href, "1") and contains(text(),"Standard")]]
```

---

Or use `Link_Text` since it is anchor rag

```
Try_Wait((By.LINK_TEXT ,"Standard"), thing_string)
Button_Click((By.LINK_TEXT ,"Standard"), thing_string)
```

Comment: Using the By.Link_Text worked perfectly. I guess I'm at a loss as to why my XPath would be invalid with the debug returning a 200. I aded the @href as I was having the same result with just a[contains(text(),"Standard")]. Could you ELI5 me on why the XPath would be invalid?

Comment: There were two anchor tags one `with` text `Standard` and one `without `text `Standard` and you have mixed that together.

Comment: Also, I forgot to add, the first solution //a[text()="Standard"] didn't work either. Only the Link_Text works. Thank you for your help on this. I clearly have more learning to do.